# Movie about a ship flying into a black hole and cannibalism

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I believe it is a horror or a thriller perhaps. The movie is a bunch of entries from the crew.

The story is that a ship with a crew on board flies into a black hole, something like point of no return or that. They go crazy and eat each other.

Comment: Do you know when you saw this? Was it new at the time? Can you remember any plot elements or memorable scenes? If so you should [edit] them in.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @user14111 If it "flies into a black hole", either it is a space ship or they are really suck at seafaring...

Comment: @SJuan76 I wouldn't rule anything out. They did, after all, go crazy and eat each other. Who knows what else happens in this world!

Comment: @SJuan76 Fair point.  Though I'd wager there probably exists at least one film or story where a singularity accidentally (or deliberately) created within Earth's atmosphere causes a normally waterbound craft to fall (or "fly", I suppose) into it.

Answer (score 62):

The movie [Event Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_(film)) (1997) features a crew investigating the return of an experimental FTL ship. The original crew used an artificial black hole as part of their drive tech, and went crazy when they crossed the event horizon, cueing much clawing of eyes from sockets and eating of flesh.

Some of the original crew experiences are accessed & shown as video logs

The crew investigating the ship experience similar madness/evil as the drive mysteriously switches itself on.

[image: Movie poster for event horizon]

Comment: [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmSLkiYwAbw).

Comment: Pandorum (2009) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandorum) also features a wayward spaceship with cannibals.

Comment: @jeffronicus I'd forgotten Pandorum, good movie, you should post a full answer.

Comment: I caught it at the cinema. God, it got under my skin. Of all the horror films I've seen, that's the only one where I can honestly say it was a great film, I'm really glad I saw it, and I never ever want to see it again.

Comment: Love seeing these comments -- Event Horizon is one of my all-time favorites exactly because of the "perfect storm" @Graham mentioned.  Laurence Fishbourne (back when he was just "Larry" IIRC), Sam Neill, mysterious dark sci-fi with ominous, potentially supernatural overtones... so good.  I think that's why I was a little let down by Pandorum -- it wasn't bad, but felt more like... I dunno...  Mad-Max-in-space, compared to EH's Hellraiser-in-space flavor.

Comment: This is a great movie but I believe it to be incorrect.  The crew does not eat each other in the movie and the movie is free flowing on the crew, not a bunch of different entries

Comment: I would be surprised if this was it. I love EH and have watched it several times, but I never would have tagged the movie with cannibalism even if there were a bit when the EH was in the other 'verse.

Comment: @USER_8675309 The log entries from the previous crew are a key part of the film. The previous crew are seen literally tearing flesh off each other - whether they actually ate it was not clear, but it's close enough.

Comment: Just to add to this: here is the "Hell" scene in slow motion: http://digg.com/video/the-bloody-hell-scenes-from-event-horizon-slowed-way-down   warning: very NSFW

Comment: @Graham I'm not disagreeing that it could be it -- alone the cannibalism is not enough to rule out Event Horizon. That being said and after watching "The Drift" below, "The Drift" fits the following criteria: Cannibalism, story told as "entries from a bunch of crew", and an "inability to leave".  I also disagree that the log entries were a "key" part of this film.. can barely even tell there is cannibalism here without slowing the ~30 seconds we get down into ultra slow motion

Comment: The interesting thing about that video is that the guy holding the gouged out eyes in his hands still has eyes in his head.  I had always assumed that he'd gouged out his own eyes.  But it must have been someone else's.  You learn something new every day.  Also, agree with others saying that the movie does not specifically invoke _cannibalism_.  Disemboweling?  Yes.  Disfigurement?  Yes.  Torture?  Sure.  Impalement on large, painful-looking spikes?  You'd better believe it.  But cannibalism?  No, not really.

Answer (score 18):

This description puts me in mind of the indi-movie *The Drift* which is available, from the production company, in full on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3XjJWqSNDg). The crew of a salvage ship goes into a dark nebula to scavenge a group of ships stranded by the "Darkwave" and finds them distressingly occupied. The occupants are warring cannibal clans who have managed to interconnect several large vessels into a rambling and horrific maze. From memory the story is told as a series of POV experiences of different crew members as they move through the ship-maze trying to complete their mission and not get eaten in the process.

Comment: Don't know if this is what OP was looking for, but at least now I have something to watch this weekend - thanks!